# Which form of verb should be used?

Tags: grammar

In the text "plug-in mobile charger in socket and turn it on and touch the other end(pin side) while standing on ground bare feet.what happened? got a shock as you have completed the circuit?NO?
now think why for 5 mins and then if you **got** the answer (well done) otherwise ask in comment"

Now I want to know which form of verb should be used "get" or "got" ?(for the highlighted/bold 'got')

Comment: Not related your question, but to question in your text: even if you would 'complete the circuit', 5V from the charger is not noticeable on your skin (don't lick your charger though).

Comment: You've got an extra "in": "plug-***in*** mobile charger ***in*** socket." -> "plug the mobile charger into the socket and ..."

Comment: Right. "Plug-in" is not a verb; it is a noun (often spelled "plugin") or an adjective. However, "Plug in" is a phrasal verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "got" is fine. If they will be considering for 5 minutes, at that time the shock will be in the past.

But there are many other problems with your paragraph. The misuse of "plug-in. . . into" has been discussed in comments. Your wording ". . . while standing on ground bare feet" should be "while standing on the ground {*barefoot/in bare feet*}". (Not to mention the unscientific nature of this test—just standing on the ground does not guarantee you are electrically grounded!)  In addition, several of your sentences are not begun with a capital letter, and your last sentence needs a couple commas.

So "got " vs. "get" is the least of your problems with this paragraph.